# Orbeon: Internationalization and others

Tags: internationalization

We are a Government agency in Uruguay (www.agesic.gub.uy).
Now our task is to evaluate Orbeon for creating forms at different state levels.

Internationalization Question
The Orbeon Professional Edition has support for internationalization.

- Which level of internationalization it has ?
- Is internationalization for action buttons supported ?
- The backend has internationalization ?
  For backend we mean: Form Builder, pre-designed forms, and so on.

Deployment Questions
- Is possible to integrate Orbeon with others Web Applications:
  Example: we have a simple Web Application with log in. After a user is logged can trigger an action, this action will show an Orbeon Form. After the user fill the Orben Form he will click "Submit" (the form is stored in Orbeon), then a Web Page of our Web App is displayed. How to access to the data filled by the user ? (without using Orbeon)

Thanks for your time.

Regards,
Bruno

Comment: You should probably contact Orbeon directly with these questions